# CSS - Positioning BG Image from Overlapping Text

Tags: css, positioning, background-image

I want to position the 16x16 icons below differently.
I want to auto-position them on the right of the text, and not behind the text.
Also, I'd like to move the icons slightly up a few pixels too.

This is the result of my code below:

[image: bgimage position stafu]

```
<span class="ico_person">John Smith</span>
<span class="ico_phone">1-555-555-5555</span>
<span class="ico_email">somewhere@someplace.com</span>
```

Here's one the styles:

```
<style>
.ico_person {
  color:#067CEA;
cursor:pointer;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:#F6F6F6;

background-image:url("/images/icons/icon_admins.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:1px 5px;
padding: 3px;
border-radius:3px 0 3px 3px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

}
</style>
```

If the image is a background, am I able to position it exactly where I need it?
Or does background-image stop that within certain boundaries?

Comment: I don't really understand your question? Could you post an image of current and desired results please?

Comment: Added a snapshot of what I have. I want to move the icons to the right, and above the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to set the horizontal and vertical position of a background using `background-position`. For example if you want the background 10px from left and 20 from top you write:

`background-position:10px 20px;`

Comment: That still keeps the image behind the span, and it goes completely out of view if I position it too far

Comment: coffeemonitor probably you can add `padding-right:20px` for the specified `span` to position the icon after the text you have.

Answer (score 0):

What Sotiris said is correct. But you could also do this:

```
.ico_person { background-position: right center; }
```

But as far as having the image next to the text instead of behind it, you should as some `padding-right` to your styling. SO for example:

```
.ico_person { padding-right:20px; }
```

Decrease/increase padding accordingly.